# How to strop text wrapping after formula in draw.io

Tags: draw.io

i am using formulas in draw.io with Latex.
Before and after every formula, the text is written in the previous/next line.
For example i want to add a simple "is" before and "?" after the formula, but as normal text, not as part of the formula.
`is $$t_B\leq time$$ ?`
But it will be written in the next line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBd2x.png)

I tried unchecking "Word Wrap" as suggested in other posts but it doesn't fix the problem.
I also couldn't find a solution in the Property Options.

Best regards,
Jan